# Are there any Logic App connectors for Oracle Fusion ERP?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, oracle-fusion-apps

Are there any Logic App connectors for Oracle Fusion ERP?

I've checked the [Microsoft list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/connectors/) and can only find the [Oracle Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/connectors/oracle/) connector, which seems amazing.

Alternatively, has one one created a custom connector?

Comment: Does Fusion support any standard protocol, SOAP/REST/Http+Xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are looking `Oracle Fusion ERP` connector on azure logic app right?

Unfortunately it is not available right now.

But you can create custom connector on `Azure Logic App` as it has full customized functionality. You could integrate your `API`, manage your `data type`, `set own business logic` and many more. Let's have a look how you could create [`Custom Connector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/)

**Step:1**

Browse to `Azure portal` and click on `All services` and search `Custom connector` Like below

[image]

**Step:2**

Select `Logic Apps Custom Connector` and `Add` your custom connector as you like. See the below screen shot.

[image]

**Step:3**

[image]

**Step:4**

[image]

**Step:5**

You can even check your `Custom Connector validation` on portal.

[image]

> **Note:** If you need full process integration guidelines you could check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218290/pull-data-fro-api-using-azure-logic-apps/56270822#56270822)

If you still have any question please feel free to share. Thanks and happy coding!

Comment: @SteveC Its pleasure. Thanks and happy coding!