# Pull data fro API using Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I need to Pull data from a 3rd party API and minor process that data and then send it to DB. Is there any connector to pull API data using Logic App? Any connector or Action? How to start.

Comment: Here is your way out how could you can call 3rd party API with your custom connector. If you have any more query feel free to share. Thanks and happy coding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you wants to fetch data from any `API` using logic App right?

Yes you can do it using `Logic Apps Custom Connector` on `azure portal` see the screen shot below:

[image]

**How to connect any API with Custom Connector:**

**Step 1: Create New Custom Connector**

To create a `Custom Connector` go to azure portal and in `All services` search for `Logic Apps Custom Connector` click on it and Add New Connector. see the screen shot:

[image]

**Step 2: Edit Custom Connector**

Once you have created new custom connector then to add your `API` with it you have to `Edit` it to configure your `API` request and response with the `new custom connector`

[image]

**Step 3: Configure Custom Connector**

There are 3 part of custom Connector

**1. General**

Here you would see `Host` enter your `API` main domain name like `dotnetavalanche.azurewebsites.net`

Leave base URL blank

[image]

**2. Security**

For test propose no authentication required just leave it blank

**3. Definition**

enter a `Summary` note , `description` but surely enter a `Operation ID` which should unique  like `TestAPI`

**Request**

Then in `Request` selection  click on `Import from sample` and enter your API method type Like `POST` or `GET`

Full `UR`L of your `API` for example: `https://dotnetavalanche.azurewebsites.net/api/PartnerBotRequest`

See the screen shot:

[image]

**Response:**

Here click on `Add default response` and add `Json` of your expected response from API

[image]

**Call Your custom Connector On Azure Logic App**

Go to `azure logic App` and click on `Http Request` on `Request Body JSON Schema` paste below `JSON`

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "description": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "email": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Then click on `Next Step` and add your custom connector like below:

[image]

Then finally add `new Step` as `Response`

Configure the response as below screen shot:

[image]

If you still have any query feel free to share. Thanks and happy coding!